# Javascript For HTML Menu

Tags: javascript, html, multidimensional-array

I have multidimensional array with object inside and its for navigation menu. I already convert that object to HTML and works fine but its so static and limited in dropdown level, in current code I just do for 2 level deep.

```js
var nav = [{ name: 'Home', route: 'home' },{ name: 'Portfolio', route: 'portfolio' },
{ name: 'Drop Down', sub: [{ name: 'Drop Down 1' },{ name: 'Drop Down 2', sub: [{ name: 'Deep Drop Down 1' }] }] }, { name: 'Last'}]

var items = []
nav.map((val,id)=>{
    var item
        if(typeof val.sub!=='undefined'){
            var item1 = []
            var item_1
            val.sub.map((val,id)=>{
                if(typeof val.sub!=='undefined'){
                    var item2 = []
                    val.sub.map((val,id)=>{
                        item2.push('<li><a href="#">'+val.name+'</a></li>')
                    })
                    item_1 = '<li class="drop-down"><a href="#">'+val.name+'</a><ul>'+item2+'</ul></li>'
                }else{
                    item_1 = '<li><a href="#">'+val.name+'</a></li>'
                }
            item1.push(item_1)
            })
            item = '<li class="drop-down"><a href="#"></a><ul>'+item1+'</ul></li>'
        }else{
            item = '<li><a href="#">'+val.name+'</a></li>'
        }
    items.push(item)
})

console.log(items)
```

Well, what if I have 5 or more level deep dropdown menu?

```
[{ name: 'Home' },
        { name: 'Portfolio' },
        { name: 'Drop Down', sub: [
            { name: 'Drop Down 1' },
            { name: 'Drop Down 2', sub: [
                { name: 'Deep Drop Down 2' }, 
                { name: 'Deep Drop Down 3', sub: [
                    { name: 'Deep Deep Drop Down 1' },
                    { name: 'Deep Deep Drop Down 2', sub: [
                        { name: 'Deep Deep Deep Drop Down 1' }] 
                    }] 
                }] 
            }
        ]}, 
        { name: 'Last'}]
```

Its gonna be demanding task and turn into ugly line of code. Any solution for this problem? Recursive solution would be better if its possible because I thinks its more efficient. Thanks.

Comment: An UX solution to this is that accept that the functionality have grown beyond what an ordinary menu should accomplish, and instead, for example, display all options as a full page modal. If product owners demand extra functionality, you should always go back to step one to figure out if the current design solution still holds up for the task, of if you need to implement a different solution.

Comment: I have little project while ago, the client demand on drop down menu but only 2 level and its not a hard task. This question is just my curiosity and I am glad I solve it with help by answer below.

Comment: Yeah, it's a great way of doing it. I recently created an native app that holds a webview. The homepage got it's own menu that is hidden in the app, so I created a menu structure in javascript for the homepage that is sent to the app. So every time we update the menu on the homepage, the app is automatically updated. It's just soo easy to work with. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about a recursive function call? Like that it doesn´t matter how many times you nest your submenus. This is a working example:

```
const buildMenu = nav => {
    const items = [];
    nav.map((val, id) => {
        items.push(`<li><a href="#">${val.name}</a></li>`);
        if (val.sub) {
            // recursive function call
            const submenu = buildMenu(val.sub);
            items.push(submenu);
        }
    });
    // wrap with ul
    return ['<ul>', ...items, '</ul>']
}

console.log(buildMenu(nav));
```

returns

```
['<ul>',
    '<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>',
    '<li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>',
    '<li><a href="#">Drop Down</a></li>',
    [
        '<ul>',
        '<li><a href="#">Drop Down 1</a></li>',
        '<li><a href="#">Drop Down 2</a></li>',
        [
            '<ul>',
            '<li><a href="#">Deep Drop Down 2</a></li>',
            '<li><a href="#">Deep Drop Down 3</a></li>',
            [
                '<ul>',
                '<li><a href="#">Deep Deep Drop Down 1</a></li>',
                '<li><a href="#">Deep Deep Drop Down 2</a></li>',
                // [] and so on...
                '</ul>'
            ],
            '</ul>'
        ],
        '</ul>'
    ],
    '<li><a href="#">Last</a></li>',
'</ul>']
```

Comment: I do a little adjust in your code and it work, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yep, it can be easily done with a recusive function

```
const datas = [{ name: 'Home' },
{ name: 'Portfolio' },
{
  name: 'Drop Down', sub: [
    { name: 'Drop Down 1' },
    {
      name: 'Drop Down 2', sub: [
        { name: 'Deep Drop Down 2' },
        {
          name: 'Deep Drop Down 3', sub: [
            { name: 'Deep Deep Drop Down 1' },
            {
              name: 'Deep Deep Drop Down 2', sub: [
                { name: 'Deep Deep Deep Drop Down 1' }]
            }]
        }]
    }
  ]
},
{ name: 'Last' }]
```

-- HTML --

```
<body>
  <ul id="test"></ul>
</body>
```

-- JS --

```
function r(data, target) {
  data.forEach(el => {
    target.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<li>" + el.name + "</li>");
    if (el.sub) {
      const ul = document.createElement("ul");
      r(el.sub, ul)
      target.lastElementChild.insertAdjacentElement("beforeend", ul);
    }
  })
}


let test = document.getElementById('test')
r(datas, test)
```

Well, I felt bad leaving you struggling with the 'ul'.

Here's a working version.

Answer (score 0):

Pure Javascript without making it a generic function.

I made some changes to the nav array.

```js
var nav = [
  { name: 'Home', route: 'home' },
  { name: 'Portfolio', route: 'portfolio' },
  { name: 'Drop Down', route: '/drop', sub: [
    { name: 'Drop Down 1', route: '/1' },
    { name: 'Drop Down 2' , route: '/2' , sub: [
      { name: 'Deep Drop Down 1' , route: '/1' }
    ]
    }] 
  },
  { name: 'Last'}];

const menu = document.querySelector('ul');
for(var r of nav) {
  var BaseLi = document.createElement('Li');
  var routeTag = document.createElement('a');
  routeTag.href = "/"+r.route;
  routeTag.innerText = r.name;
  BaseLi.appendChild(routeTag);
  if(r.sub) {
    var subMenu = document.createElement('ul');
    for(var s of r.sub){
      var SubLi = document.createElement('Li');
      var routeTag = document.createElement('a');
      routeTag.href = "/"+r.route +"/"+s.route;
      routeTag.innerText = s.name;
      SubLi.appendChild(routeTag)
      subMenu.appendChild(SubLi);
    }
    BaseLi.appendChild(subMenu);
    if(s.sub) {
       var subMenu2 = document.createElement('ul');
      for(var s2 of s.sub){
        var SubLi2 = document.createElement('Li');
        var routeTag = document.createElement('a');
        routeTag.href = "/"+r.route +"/"+s.route+"/"+s2.route;
        routeTag.innerText = s2.name;
        SubLi2.appendChild(routeTag)
        subMenu2.appendChild(SubLi2);
      } 
      SubLi.appendChild(subMenu2);
    }
  }
  menu.appendChild(BaseLi);  
}
```

```html
<ul></ul>
```